# How to replace name of a folder in a path?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Replace name of a folder (ab) ahead of anime or movie folder in a path. Replace ab folder with ac.

```
File has list of paths:
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/film
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/ab/cartoon
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/ab/cartoon1
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/ab/movie/adjeifjeo/movie
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/ab/anime/adjeifjeo/anime
C://file1/file2/file3/ab/anime/adjeifjeo/anime1
C://file1/file2/ab/anime/adjeifjeo/anime2
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/file6/ab/anime/adjeifjeo/anime3


Output:
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/film
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/ab/cartoon
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/ab/cartoon1
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/ac/movie/adjeifjeo/movie
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime
C://file1/file2/file3/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime1
C://file1/file2/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime2
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/file6/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime3
```

**ab folder is always present 1 folder ahead of movie or anime folder.**

**Name of current ab folder always changes. Sometimes its ad, ae, af, ag (it's random).**

**Only path with movie or anime folder should replace name of ab folder with ac.**

```
sed 's/\/ab\//\/ac\//'
```

**This does not solve as "ab" keeps changing and all path with "ab" will be replaced with "ac".**

Comment: The last bold line does not make it clear. Try the [`awk` solution](https://ideone.com/scQozV) like `awk -F/ -v OFS='/' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i=="anime" || $i=="movie") { $(i-1)="ac"; i=NF}}1' file`

Comment: Did anything work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's;[[:alpha:]]*\(/movie/\|/anime/\);ac\1;' input_file
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/film
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/ab/cartoon
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/ab/cartoon1
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/ac/movie/adjeifjeo/movie
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime
C://file1/file2/file3/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime1
C://file1/file2/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime2
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/file6/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime3
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `sed -E` and match a single char a-z after matching `/a`

```
sed -E 's~/a[a-z]/(movie|anime)/~/ac/\1/~' file
```

Output

```
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/film
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/ab/cartoon
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/ab/cartoon1
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/ac/movie/adjeifjeo/movie
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime
C://file1/file2/file3/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime1
C://file1/file2/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime2
C://file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/file6/ac/anime/adjeifjeo/anime3
```

Answer (score 0):

suggesting:

```
 sed 's|/ab/|/ac/|'
```